# iphone - handle web page with in the application

Tags: iphone

i'm currently working on iphone app which has a web view.
i'm pulling a web page from internet and updating the web view.
the web page has 3 text inputs: username, mail id and response code.
it also has a button "play now". on click of play now, the data is posted to server and some processing is done there......
now,in my application, on click of "play now", i want to remove the web view and show my next view in application.
can you please help me to achieve this or some solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the webview delegate

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

You can retrieve the URL of the request from the request parameter of the method. Check whether it matches the URL of play now button.

Comment: Hi Anil, The following is the URL which i'm showing in web view. Can you please see the page source and tell me which URL I've to check?           http://www.allslotscasino.com/download_frame_iphone.html

Comment: Put your link in a desktop browser, fill the details and click on the submit button. The link you are getting after submitting the request is the one you are searching for. 

http://www.allslotscasino.com/download_frame_iphone_thanks.html